# init unable to find root device on computer in restoration

Tags: grub2, initramfs, mbr

I'm a bit out of solution on this one :
I am restoring an old computer (15 years old...), which was running archlinux.
I have inadvertently erased the pacman package database (and all /var ...), and I am trying to make it boot again without reinstalling (there are some /etc other stuff I would like to keep...).

I has no support for EFI, grub is installed on the disk mbr, with its configuration on a dedicated /boot partition.

I have used a Manjaro live cd to chroot into it and upgrade the base, linux, and all the fundamental packages (I would like the system to boot so that I continue reinstalling the other packages from the running system).

However, I can't get a working initramfs. I have tried multiple times to do the whole `mkinitcpio -P`, `grub-install` and `grub-mkconfig`, but when restarting, I always get the "Unable to find root device '...'`

I've tried to edit the command line from grub, but neither the `UUID=...`, the `LABEL=...` nor the `/dev/...` versions works... (by the way, to grub config seems correct since the UUID matches the one printed by `lsblk`

What could I have missed ? Is there some files (not tracked by pacman) from outpackage that could interfer ? Which package should I force reinstall to get a working initramfs ?

(EDIT)

initrd doesn't give much (only the traditional `device .. not found. Skipping fsck` and `Unable to find root device ...`. There is also a `sh: can't access tty: job control turned off`. I don't have keyboard access.

The grub installation is simple `grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sdb`

The grub command line is :

```
load_video
set gfxpayload=keep
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd1,msdos1'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ...
linux /vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=... rw loglevel=3 quiet
initrd /initramfs-linux.img
```

EDIT2

I was able to plug PS/2 keyboard, and I can use the emergency shell now...
In /dev, there is no hard drive listed. I guess this is why it can't find the root fs...

Comment: What kind of device are we talking about here?  Are you using raid or LVM?  If so you will need those packages installed to generate an initrd that can understand them.

Comment: None of them just regular MBR partitions with primary and extended one

Comment: I edited again, since I can use the keyboard now in the emergency shell

Comment: If it is an old PATA hard drive then your kernel may not have the old IDE driver enabled, figuring that everyone moved to SATA long ago so the libata AHCI driver is used.  You may just need to build the kernel yourself and enable the old driver.